how to create a variable list for WHERE/IN function?
I have a huge list of IDs I'm searching through from a large data set.
When I try to search for the IDs using IN, it says I've gone beyond character limits so won't run.
If I'm to split these into manageable size (see below) it'd take me really long time due to the size.
Is it possible to have a variable that contains all the list of IDs I want, and in the where function use IN VAR?
If I am to split into smaller chunks
(customer_id in ('1', '2', '3', ..., '1000')
or
customer_id in ('1001', '1002', '1003', ..., '2000')
or
customer_id in ('2001', '2002', '2003', ..., '3000'))

What I want (verbatim)
Cust_ID_List IN ('1', '2', '3', ... '3000') -- VARAIBLE
SELECT * FROM DATA
WHERE ID IN Cust_ID_List


No. You can use BETWEEN, though. WHERE (customer_id BETWEEN '1' and '1000') OR (customer_id BETWEEN '1001' and '2000') OR (customer_id BETWEEN '3' and '3000')for the small groups, or the shorterBETWEEN '1' AND '3000'`

I would probably just insert your values into another table, then write something like select * from table1 where customer_id in (select customer_id from table2)

I'd do what @Isolated said, but I'd do an inner join to the table to accomplish the filter instead.

@Isolated's approach is much better than a long query. Many engines have hardcoded limits in the hundreds of values.

In SQL you can create a User-Defined Table to insert the IDs and then use it as any other table with JOINS for exmaple.
CREATE TYPE [CustomerIdentifiers] AS TABLE(
    CustomerID NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @CustomerIds AS CustomerIdentifiers

INSERT INTO @CustomerIds VALUES('1')
INSERT INTO @CustomerIds VALUES('2')
INSERT INTO @CustomerIds VALUES('3')
INSERT INTO @CustomerIds VALUES('4')
...

And then:
SELECT *
FROM Data d
INNER JOIN @CustomerIds c ON c.[CustomerID] = d.[ID]

or with EXISTS
SELECT *
FROM Data d
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM @CustomerIds c
  WHERE c.[CustomerID] = d.[ID]
)


EXISTS is horribly to read in this case, an IN clause would be far simpler.

Crate a function:
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[sp_Split](@text nvarchar(max), @delimiter nvarchar(20) = ' ')
    RETURNS @Strings TABLE
    (    
      position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
      value varchar(8000)   
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @index int 
    SET @index = -1 
    WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0) 
      BEGIN  
        SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)  
        IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)  
          BEGIN   
            INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
              BREAK  
          END  
        IF (@index > 1)  
          BEGIN   
            INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))   
            SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index - len(@delimiter) +1))  
          END  
        ELSE 
          SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index - len(@delimiter) +1)) 
        END
      RETURN
    END

call it
DECLARE @var_ids as nvarchar(max) = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,99,999,3000';

    SELECT * 
    FROM DATA d 
    INNER JOIN dbo.sp_Split(@var_ids, ',') sp_Split ON 
    d.ID = sp_Split.[value]

